# .htaccess: mod-rewrite; subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am working on a new website bud I want to create a nice looking urls for my users. I don't know anything of `htaccess` and could not find my solution on google.

I need to link:

- `user.mywebsite.com` **to>>** `mywebsite.com/users/user`
- `user2.mywebsite.com/contact` **to>>** `mywebsite.com/users/user2/contact`

Some links may not be linked like:

- `www.mywebsite.com` may not link to `mywebsite.com/users/www`

Is this possibe to do with `htaccess`?
If yes can someone explain it to me?

Comment: If I understand your last question I will explain it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# the request URI doesn't already start with /users/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/

# host doesn't start with www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]

# host starts with something else
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mywebsite\.com$  [NC]

# rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/%1/$1  [L]
```

This will make it so when someone enters http://joe.mywebsite.com/some/page.html they will be served the file in **/users/joe/some/page.html**

Comment: Why it give me 500 error? I am using codeigniter and using pretty url without index.php exists on my htaccess, can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Redirecting your old links to new ones.

```
Redirect user.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com/users/user
Redirect user2.mywebsite.com/contact mywebsite.com/users/user2/contact
```

Comment: sorry this isn't what i'm looking for. need someting to get it work always with every account

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [VirtualDocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/vhosts/mass.html#homepages)

> e.g. the documents for www.user.isp.com are found in /home/user/.

```
# include part of the server name in the filenames
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%2/docs

# single cgi-bin directory
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /www/std-cgi/
```