# How to rewrite my  page URL to pagename.siteurl.com

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting

I have Dreamweaver CS3 and i was wondering if it is possible to make a html page go from idreesinc.com/research.html to research.idreesinc.com. Is it possible and if so how do i do it? I have to actually MAKE a page and not just a redirect.
Thanks!

Comment: The term you are looking for is `URL Rewrite`.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490184/htaccess-mod-rewrite-subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a "rewrite", it's a redirect - but it'll be the easiest for you as a beginner.

Easy with JS. Not the "best" way mind you, but the easiest.

Add this inside the  tags or right after the opening  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'http://research.idreesinc.com';
</script>
```

If you're looking for how to make a subdomain (subdomain.domain.com), you need to search:
["How to make a subdomain"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS435US435&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20make%20a%20subdomain)

Comment: Oh so it is called a subdomain? I was looking for something completley different. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit a file in the root of your idreesinc.com site called '.htaccess'

Insert the line:

```
Redirect 301 /research.html http://research.idreesinc.com
```

Comment: Ummm sorry but how? I am new to this whole "website" thing so could you help me?

Comment: actually now that i think about i need to somehow create a page with the new url. not just redirect to it