# Dynamic subdomain redirection to URL variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am trying to redirect any subdomain of my website to a page by using the subdomain's name as a variable but without the URL to actually change.

e.g. 
http://SUBDOMAIN-NAME.website.com 
to poing to: 
http://www.website.com/view/SUBDOMAIN-NAME
but with the URL staying as 
https://soundcloud.com/bugprentice/im-so-tired

I am on an APACHE server and I would like to use .htaccess rules

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess: mod-rewrite; subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490184/htaccess-mod-rewrite-subdomain)

Comment: Thank you for that Emil, but the article you proposed is not for dynamic subdomains. The names are hardcoded.

Comment: Then I suggest you read it again and also check out the answers, because that question is about dynamic subdomains.